# Getting a python warning when running playbook EC2 inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am really new to Ansible and I hate getting warnings when I run a playbook. This environment is being used for my education.

Environment:

- AWS EC2
- 4 Ubuntu 20
- 3 Amazon Linux2 hosts

Inventory

- using the dynamic inventory script

playbook

- just runs a simple ping against all hosts. I wanted to test the inventory

warning

- [WARNING]: Platform linux on host XXXXXX.amazonaws.com is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change the
  meaning of that path. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-core/2.11/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.

Things I have tried

- updated all sym links on hosts to point to the python3 version
- adding the line "ansible_python_interpreter      = /usr/bin/python" to "/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg"
- I am relying on that cfg file

I would like to know how to solve this. since I am not running a static inventory, I didn't think that I could specific an interpreter on a per host or group of hosts. While the playbook runs, it seems that something is not configured correctly and I would like to get that sorted. This is only present on the Amazon Linux instances. the Ubuntu instances are fine.

Michael

Answer (score 7):

You can edit your ansible.cfg and set auto_silent mode:

```sh
interpreter_python=auto_silent
```

Check reference here:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html

Comment: This would go in the "[defaults]" section of ansible.cfg.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you. I did find another route that work though I am sure that you suggest would also work.

I was using the wrong configuration entry. I was using

```
ansible_python_interpreter = /usr/bin/python
```

when I should have been using

```
interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python
```

on each host I made sure that /usr/bin/python sym link was pointing and the correct version.

according to the documentation

- for **individual hosts and groups**, use the ansible_python_interpreter inventory variable
- **globally**, use the interpreter_python key in the [defaults] section of ansible.cfg

Regards, Michael.

Answer (score 0):

For me, updating to the most recent version of ansible was enough (ansible [core 2.14.3])